# Would this be the right way to select elements that have a ".subj" ending?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have this code:

```
for(var i=0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
   var subjects = [];

   var key, value;
   key = localStorage.key(i);
   value = localStorage.getItem(key);

   var keysplit = key.split(".");

   if(keysplit[keysplit.length] == "subj") {
       subjects.push(value);
   }

}
```

I am trying to select all the keys that have a .subj ending, but this does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: you want to make keysplit a var too, probably

Comment: @seanizer I just did that and it did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `length` property returns the number of items in the array, and as the index is zero based there is no item with that index.

Use `length - 1` to get the last item:

```
if (keysplit[keysplit.length - 1] === "subj") {
```

Answer (score 1):

Other possibilities:

```
if(key.substr(key.lastIndexOf('.')) == ".subj")
//or
var suffix = '.subj';
if(key.lastIndexOf(suffix) == key.length - suffix.length)
```

See: [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)